# Use another object field value in spring message interpolation

Tags: spring, validation, interpolation

I am trying, if it's possible, to customize a message of a constraint with a value that is not actually the one that is being validated but belong to the same class.

```
public Car {
  @NotEmpty(message = The car of the model '${this.model}' requires a plate_number)
  String plate_number;

  String model;
}
```

And now after creating a new instance of it

```
Car myCar = new Car(null, Audi);
```

and having validated, I want to get the message "The car of the model Audi requires a plate_number"

I do not know if its possible. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know about `@NotEmpty` annotation because your are creating a `Car` object using `constructor` and I also know when using `javax` or `jakarta` validation usually it is on `DTO` exposed into REST endpoints.

As a alternative you can using `Assert.notNull` into contructor:

```
public class Car {

  private String model;

  private String plate_number;


  public Car(String model, String plate_number) {
    this.model = model;
    Assert.notNull(plate_number,
        "The car of the model " + this.model + " requires a plate_number");
    this.plate_number = plate_number;
  }
}
```

And now when you will pass:

```
Car car = new Car("Audi", null);
```

In console you will have next one error message:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The car of the model Audi  requires a plate_number
```

Comment: The idea is more to use the constraint properties to launch the customized message instead of implementing the code in a method.

Comment: Based on example that you provide.  `Car myCar = new Car(null, Audi);` I don’t think that is possible to use with annotation

Comment: I mean that you are using pure Java code, but annotation `@NotEmpty` is from javax or Jakarta api

Comment: Yep, it's what I supposed

Comment: was my answer enough good for help ?

Comment: Yeah, but not to close this item I need a clear answer saying that is sure that what I am requesting it's not possible for sure or the solution if it exists

Comment: In my answer I am talking about it, you can’t use one field object as dynamic value into annotation for another field, to do it you should create a custom annotation that do it with  a custom validation but in your case you are not invoking the ValidationService to check it you just create a object through constructor that don’t use annotations from constraint validator to check the whether of values. I mean in such case these kind of annotations is just a text that do nothing. A good way for you now is what I propose in answer do do validation in constructor.

Comment: Indeed, was a helping answer